cannot create python virtual environment with Ubuntu on windows partitions
I have Pop!_OS dualbooted with Windows. I can create python virtual environments without any problems in anywhere in my linux file system. But, when I try to create one (with python -m venv venv) in windows partitions (not drive C:, any other) which are mounted and then used on linux, I get this error:
Error: Command '['/media/parsa/D2942F56942F3BFB/.../venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Using virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 venv will also cause this error:
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/usr/bin/python3' -> '/media/parsa/D2942F56942F3BFB/.../venv/bin/python'

I didn't have this problem before and I don't know why it's happening right now.

The windows file systems lack the features required to usLinyx virtual environment on them. Put the venv into a Linux filesystem. You can't use it on Window anyway.

As I mentioned in the question, I could do this without any problems before. I don't know what's stopping me now. And by the way, I'm not gonna use the virtual env on windows, but I'll probably need the codes.
